# How to parse a value from javascript assignment statement in objective-c

Tags: javascript, iphone, regex

I'm working with an api that requires a key only found when doing an Http GET request from the initial web page.  So in my app I do a simple GET request and get back the xhtml. I'm looking for advice about how to pull a specific value from a javascript assignment statement found in this response.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">abc.123.key = 'Ikc8StJJiJ2Pq/Dl+iUz3MFzk6qnL7mz6hFFkn5LtZM=';</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

In the example above I'm looking to capture the value "Ikc8StJJiJ2Pq/Dl+iUz3MFzk6qnL7mz6hFFkn5LtZM=" from the assignment of abc.123.key.  Should I do a simple regex and if so what would a simple example look like to get me started?

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading this xhtml into an `UIWebView` you can do the following

```
NSString* key = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"abc.123.key"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drill down using XPath to get to the script tag, with an expression like `/html/body/script/text()`, and then use a simple regex to get the key you want.

Comment: Any way I could get a little more detail on this solution in pure XPath? The typical google search isn't returning much of value for a simple example like this (library free that is).